# how to find outliers in multiple rows when the first column is in id form in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, aggregate, plyr

I have data that looks like this

```
mem_id age1 age2 age3 age4 age5 age6 age7 age8 age9 age10
1       3     5    5   6     7   8     9   10    11  15
2       5     6    7   8     10  10    11   11   12  13
3       7     7    7   7     8    8     8    9    9   9
4       8     8    8   8     8    8     9    9    9   9 
5       12    13   14  9    15   16    16   16   16  16
```

I want to find out the outliers in each row  using the criteria that the value of an element in a row for a particular `mem_id` is not in the range of Q1-1.5*Inter Quartile Range,Q3-1.5*Inter Quartile Range where Q1 is the first quartile and Q3 is the third quartile then we classify it has an outlier

so I want an output like this

```
mem_id  outliers
  1      age2 3, age1 5
  2       age3 6,age4 7
```

That my output will tell me the location of the outliers and value of the outliers for each mem_id.

Comment: In the future please can you post your data using the `dput` function as it makes it a lot easier for people to pickup and run with :)

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by > 1.5 IQR .  Normally you would have some point of reference for example  >  mean + 1.5 * IQR

Comment: @C_G : I think you want to say `+/-` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what your after (though I am a bit confused still about what your output should look like) but this code will create a True / False grid where all your outlying values will have a True value and all your in-lying values will have a False value

```
x <- c (1    ,   3 ,    5  ,  5  , 6  ,   7   , 8  ,   9  , 10 ,   11 , 15,
2     ,  5  ,   6  ,  7  , 8  ,   10  ,10  ,  11  , 11 ,  12  ,13,
3    ,   7 ,    7  ,  7  , 7  ,   8   , 8  ,   8  ,  9 ,   9  , 9,
4   ,    8   ,  8  ,  8  , 8  ,   8   , 8  ,   9  ,  9 ,   9  , 9 ,
5    ,   12  ,  13 ,  14 , 9  ,  15   ,16  ,  16  , 16 ,  16  ,16)


mat <- matrix(x , byrow = T , ncol = 11)

mat2 <- mat[ ,-1 ]


i <- apply( mat2 , 1 , IQR)
m <- apply( mat2 , 1 , mean )

upper <- sweep(mat2 , 1 ,  m + 1.5* i , ">")
lower <- sweep(mat2 , 1 ,  m - 1.5* i , "<")

(outlie <- upper | lower)
```